# Call child component method from parent class - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I have created a child component which has a method I want to invoke.

When I invoke this method it only fires the `console.log()` line, it will not set the `test` property??

Below is the quick start Angular app with my changes.

**Parent**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NotifyComponent }  from './notify.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template:
    `
    <button (click)="submit()">Call Child Component Method</button>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    private notify: NotifyComponent;

    constructor() { 
      this.notify = new NotifyComponent();
    }

    submit(): void {
        // execute child component method
        notify.callMethod();
    }
}
```

**Child**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'notify',
    template: '<h3>Notify {{test}}</h3>'
})
export class NotifyComponent implements OnInit {
   test:string; 
   constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }

    callMethod(): void {
        console.log('successfully executed.');
        this.test = 'Me';
    }
}
```

How can I set the `test` property as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a method of the child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31013461/call-a-method-of-the-child-component)

Comment: You can check this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53057589/6663458

Answer (score 391, accepted):

You can do this by using `@ViewChild` for more info check this [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html)

> **With type selector**

child component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-cmp',
  template: '<p>child</p>'
})
class ChildCmp {
  doSomething() {}
}
```

parent component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'some-cmp',
  template: '<child-cmp></child-cmp>',
  directives: [ChildCmp]
})
class SomeCmp {

  @ViewChild(ChildCmp) child:ChildCmp;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // child is set
    this.child.doSomething();
  }
}
```

> **With string selector**

child component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-cmp',
  template: '<p>child</p>'
})
class ChildCmp {
  doSomething() {}
}
```

parent component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'some-cmp',
  template: '<child-cmp #child></child-cmp>',
  directives: [ChildCmp]
})
class SomeCmp {

  @ViewChild('child') child:ChildCmp;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // child is set
    this.child.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Comment: I followed your approach, but I'm getting error while using directives: [ChildCmp], The error says: directives' does not exist in type 'Component'. I've googled it and found directives is deprecated in rc5. So how to handle it on the newer version. Please help.

Comment: try this link https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction and comment the directives link

Comment: How to make it work when there is multiple children of same class??

Comment: @rashfmnb "Declaration expected". An error is coming when I try to write @ViewChild('child') child:ChildCmp;in the component. Please help! And Also i cannot import the same in the directive it gives me error like "directive: (typeof EmployeeProfileC...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'directive' does not exist in type 'Component'."

Comment: This a correct answer, but it produces _tightly coupled components_. A better pattern is to use `Input` properties: an observable to which the child reacts by calling its _own_ internal function. See user6779899 's answer

Comment: A gotcha here is if the child component is in an *ngIf.  When the *ngIf condition is satisfied, the type of the ViewChild is ElementRef rather than "ChildCmp" or whatever.  And as an ElementRef, you can't call the method.

Comment: this approach is not scalable. what about you have multiple child components?

Comment: The purpose of this answer is to just give the basic idea.

Answer (score 141):

I think most easy way is using Subject. In below example code, the child will be notified each time 'tellChild()' is called.

**Parent.component.ts**

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
...
export class ParentComp {
  changingValue: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
        
  tellChild() {
    this.changingValue.next(true);
  }
}
```

**Parent.component.html**

```
<my-comp [changing]="changingValue"></my-comp>
```

**Child.component.ts**

```
...
export class ChildComp implements OnInit{
  @Input() changing: Subject<boolean>;
  
  ngOnInit(){
    this.changing.subscribe(v => { 
      console.log('value is changing', v);
    });
  }
}
```

Working sample on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-parent-child-subject)

Comment: It is an elegant solution, however it does not work properly in all cases, probably due Angular change detection not working from subscribe.

Comment: Neat !  For simpler cases, you can avoid the Subject/Subscribe overhead by passing an object that has a callback method to the child. Similar to the above, the child overrides the callback to receive indications from the parent.

Comment: @shr any chance you can share your solution to pass an object with callback ?

Comment: @ImadElHitti, added a sample solution as a separate answer, since code is not allowed within comments.

Comment: This one is elegant solution, this should be the accepted answer, just change import method like import {Subject} from 'rxjs';

Comment: A subject is not necessarily required here because it is a one-way relationship, an EventEmitter would be sufficient for this job.

Comment: Nice, I was looking for something like this, it's a _loosely coupling_ approach. However, the subject in child should be only an `Observable`, the child must not be able to emit events.

Comment: This is indeed the best solution as ViewChild won't work with content projection, you'll have to use ContentChild instead and after a while it can be complex to know which use case, while Subject is consistant.

Answer (score 86):

This Worked for me ! For Angular 2 , Call child component method in parent component

**Parent.component.ts**

```
    import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    import { ChildComponent } from '../child/child'; 
    @Component({ 
               selector: 'parent-app', 
               template: `<child-cmp></child-cmp>` 
              }) 
    export class parentComponent implements OnInit{ 
        @ViewChild(ChildComponent ) child: ChildComponent ; 

        ngOnInit() { 
           this.child.ChildTestCmp(); } 
}
```

---

**Child.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({ 
  selector: 'child-cmp', 
  template: `<h2> Show Child Component</h2><br/><p> {{test }}</p> ` 
})
export class ChildComponent {
  test: string;
  ChildTestCmp() 
  { 
    this.test = "I am child component!"; 
  }
 }
```

---

Comment: What is ChildVM in this line:  @ViewChild(ChildComponent ) child: ChildVM;

Comment: @WaleedShahzaib I think OP meant `ChildComponent` by `ChildVM`

Comment: I thought this would create a separate instance of the component but it actually calls the function from your instance with it's variables in the current state of that component, holy cow! this method is way better than the first answer!

Comment: I am always getting Undefined value of "this.child"

Comment: I have the same problem as @AmbujKhanna

Comment: My guess for 'this.child' being undefined is that either ViewChild is pointing at something that doesn't exist in the template, or you are trying to access it too early in the lifecycle, e.g. in the constructor.

Comment: NullInjectorError: No provider for ChildComponent!

Answer (score 20):

Angular – Call Child Component’s Method in Parent Component’s Template

You have ParentComponent and ChildComponent that looks like this.

> parent.component.html

[image]

> parent.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

> child.component.html

```
<p>
  This is child
</p>
```

> child.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent {
  constructor() {
  }

  doSomething() {
    console.log('do something');
  }
}
```

When serve, it looks like this:

[image]

When user focus on ParentComponent’s input element, you want to call ChildComponent’s doSomething() method.

Simply do this:

1. Give app-child selector in parent.component.html a DOM variable name
   **(prefix with # – hashtag)**, in this case we call it appChild.
2. Assign expression value (of the method you want to call) to input element’s focus event.

[image]

> The result:

[image]

Comment: OK but we also want to do it programmatically using ts

Comment: For use from within the component: `@ViewChild('appChild', { static: false }) appChild: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;` and later use `this.appChild.doSomething()`

Answer (score 20):

parent.component.html

```
<app-child #childComponent></app-child>
```

parent.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-parent',
    templateUrl: './app-parent.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app-parent.component.scss']
})
export class ParentComponent {
    @ViewChild('childComponent', {static: false}) childComponent: ChildComponent;

    anyMethod(): void {
        childComponent.updateData() // updateData is a child method
    }
}
```

child.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-child',
    templateUrl: './app-child.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app-child.component.scss']
})
export class ChildComponent {
    updateData(): void {
      // Method code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot find name `ChildComponent`. Do I need to import something else beside `ViewChild`?

Comment: Solution to my own issue: `import {ChildComponent} from './whateverpath/child.component`. This is the easiest. Recommended!

Comment: This is what helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

user6779899's answer is neat and more generic
However, based on the request by Imad El Hitti, a light weight solution is proposed here. This can be used when a child component is tightly connected to one parent only.

**Parent.component.ts**

```
export class Notifier {
    valueChanged: (data: number) => void = (d: number) => { };
}

export class Parent {
    notifyObj = new Notifier();
    tellChild(newValue: number) {
        this.notifyObj.valueChanged(newValue); // inform child
    }
}
```

**Parent.component.html**

```
<my-child-comp [notify]="notifyObj"></my-child-comp>
```

**Child.component.ts**

```
export class ChildComp implements OnInit{
    @Input() notify = new Notifier(); // create object to satisfy typescript
    ngOnInit(){
      this.notify.valueChanged = (d: number) => {
            console.log(`Parent has notified changes to ${d}`);
            // do something with the new value 
        };
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 8):

Consider the following example,

```
import import { AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CountdownTimerComponent }  from './countdown-timer.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-countdown-parent-vc',
    templateUrl: 'app-countdown-parent-vc.html',
    styleUrl: [app-countdown-parent-vc.css]
})
export class CreateCategoryComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild(CountdownTimerComponent, {static: false}) private timerComponent: CountdownTimerComponent;
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.timerComponent.startTimer();
    }

    submitNewCategory(){
        this.ngAfterViewInit();
    }
}
```

[Read more about @ViewChild here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild).

Comment: this is the best answer.

Comment: There was no need to explicitly call the ngAfterViewInit(). it will be called automatically if implemented on the class

Comment: There's a need to explicitly call the `ngAfterViewInit()` because we explicitly need to tell Angular to call method `startTimer()`, which is in component `CountdownTimerComponent`

Answer (score 0):

I had an exact situation where the Parent-component had a `Select` element in a form and on submit, I needed to call the relevant Child-Component's method according to the selected value from the select element.

**Parent.HTML:**

```
<form (ngSubmit)='selX' [formGroup]="xSelForm">
    <select formControlName="xSelector">
      ...
    </select>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<child [selectedX]="selectedX"></child>
```

**Parent.TS:**

```
selX(){
  this.selectedX = this.xSelForm.value['xSelector'];
}
```

**Child.TS:**

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() public selectedX;

  //ngOnChanges will execute if there is a change in the value of selectedX which has been passed to child as an @Input.

  ngOnChanges(changes: { [propKey: string]: SimpleChange }) {
    this.childFunction();
  }
  childFunction(){ }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I used `EventEmitter` for this.

**parent.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-parent",
  template: '<app-child listener="notify"></app-child>' +
            '<button (click)="notify.emit()">Call child function</button>',
  //...
})
export class ParentComponent {
  notify: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>()
}
```

**child.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-child",
  template: "<i>Child component text</i>",
  //...
})
export class ChildComponent {
  #listener: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>()
  @Input()
  set listener(emitter: EventEmitter<void>) {
    this.#listener.unsubscribe()
    this.#listener = emitter
    this.#listener.subscribe(this.childFunction.bind(this))
  }

  childFunction() {
    console.log("Child function called")
  }
}
```

Good parts of this approach:

- reliable - works even if you change `EventEmitter` (value of notify property in `ParentComponent`) later in code
- keeps component decoupled

Bad part:

- little bit more coding is needed compared to other solutions

---

If you need to pass some data, replace `void` (in `EventEmitter<void>`) with desired type.

If you need to pass more than 1 parameter, then I would suggest to create `interface` and pass data as single object containing all parameters you need to pass to `ChildComponent`. Quicker (and dirtier) solution to this would be to set type as `any` and pass whatever object you want.

### Example with passing object as parameter

**parent.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-parent",
  template: '<app-child listener="notify"></app-child>' +
            '<button (click)="callChild()">Call child function</button>',
  //...
})
export class ParentComponent {
  notify: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>()

  callChild() {
    this.notify.emit({title: 'Parent call', id: 1})
  }
}
```

**child.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-child",
  template: "<i>Child component text</i>",
  //...
})
export class ChildComponent {
  #listener: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>()
  @Input()
  set listener(emitter: EventEmitter<any>) {
    this.#listener.unsubscribe()
    this.#listener = emitter
    this.#listener.subscribe(this.childFunction.bind(this))
  }

  childFunction(data: any) {
    console.log("Child function called")
    console.log(data)
  }
}
```