# Change CSS depending on Angular scope value

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to change my css based on an angular scope variable. Let me explain my self like this.

```
$scope.entries = [{
    status: 'denied' 
}
```

I need to make it so that the status of the element changes the background of the element: if the status is denied, red, and so on.

Comment: check this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38974896/call-child-component-method-from-parent-class-angular-2/38974968#38974968

Comment: use ng-class https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this if you dont want to use ng-class

```
<span class="status-{{var}}"></span>
```

css

```
.status-denied{
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your view, you can conditionally apply classes to your html element by using the ngClass directive. [Documentation here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

You'll want to create a css class with the styling that you want, and then apply that class when some condition is met, using an expression inside ng-class.

An example from the documentation:

**CSS**

```
.base-class {
  transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
}

.base-class.my-class {
  color: red;
  font-size:3em;
}
```

**View**

```
<input id="setbtn" type="button" value="set" ng-click="myVar='my-class'">
<input id="clearbtn" type="button" value="clear" ng-click="myVar=''">
<br>
<span class="base-class" ng-class="myVar">Sample Text</span>
```

[Plunker from docs](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)