# Pass data from child to parent component Angular2 (reactive and template driven combined)

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, components

being very new to Angular 2 ( and Angular in general ) , I've encountered a situation with my colleague where he decided to go for the template driven approach and me for the reactive driven approach. We've both created components. His being a search product component and mine being a credidcard component.

**What does it do and the wish**

From a searchbox if you select a creditcard from the dropdownbox my component will be rendered(and validated when a number is being inserted).

I wish to bind the data from my creditcard component ( being the child ) to the model of the SearchProductModel that he defined. 
I saw something similar which resembles my problem a bit here is the post ([Pass data from child to parent component Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107167/pass-data-from-child-to-parent-component-angular2)).

These are the components and templates

*creditcard.component.ts*

```
@Component({
selector:'creditcard',
templateUrl:'./app/creditcard/creditcard.component.html' 
})

export class CreditcardComponent {
creditForm: FormGroup 

ccnumber = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, validateCreditcard]);

constructor(fb:FormBuilder){
this.creditForm = fb.group({"ccnumber":this.ccnumber})
}
```

*search-product.component.ts*

```
    @Component({
    selector:'search-product',
    templateUrl:'./app/search/search-product.component.html' 
    })

    export class SearchProductComponent{
products: Product[]
model = new SearchProductModel();
searchResult:string;

constructor(private searchProductService: SearchProductService){}

ngOnInit(): void {
this.searchProductService.getProducts().subscribe(products => this.products = products, error => console.log(error));
}

onSubmit(): void {
this.searchProductService.searchProduct(this.model).subscribe(result => this.searchResult = result, 
error => console.log(error));;
}
```

*search-product.component.html*

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #searchForm="ngForm" autocomplete="off">
<p>
<md-select placeholder="Product (optioneel)" [(ngModel)]="model.productId" name="product-id" id="product" style="width:250px">
 <md-option *ngFor="let product of products" [value]="product.Id">{{product.Name}}</md-option>
</md-select>
</p>

<div [ngSwitch]="model.productId">
 <p *ngSwitchCase="1">
<creditcard></creditcard>
</p>
<p *ngSwitchDefault>
<md-input-container style="width: 250px">
<input mdInput [(ngModel)]="model.productNumber" name="product-number" id="product-number" required/>
<md-error>productnumber required</md-error>
</md-input-container>

<button md-button type="submit" id="btn-zoek">Search</button>
</form>
```

*creditcard.component.html*

```
<form [formGroup]="creditcardForm">
<div class="form-group">
<md-input-container>
 <input mdInput formControlname="creditcardnumber" id="creditcardnumber" name="creditcardnumber"/>
<div *ngIf="creditForm.get('creditcardnumber').dirty && creditcardForm.get('creditcardnumber').hasError('validCreditcard')">Not correct creditcard</div>
</md-input-container>
</div>
</form>
```

As I understand it, the mixed template driven and reactive approach is not advisable so I will be refactoring this in the future. But for now I wonder how I can make it possible for my creditcard input to get into his model.productId ( see the code). 
Bear with me, I'm new in this and I'm just having a hard time wrapping my head around it.

Help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I made a small mistake that has led me to believe my solution didn't work. 
However it did work. I just followed the explanation I've put in the link above. 
Added the Emitter in my component and subscribed the other component to the events of mine. 
That did the trick.