# Angular - Getting data from a child component?

Tags: angular

I have a table that contains users records. There is a column for "tags" that allow you to tag the record with one or more values.

For this, I created an edit button on the row. Once clicked, I show a component that I have wrapped in an `ngIf`.

```
<span *ngIf="inEditMode(r.RuleParentID, a.AttributeID)">
 <app-inline-select [selected]="a" [source]="fetchSourceList(a.AttributeID)" [ruleParentID]="r.RuleParentID" [attributeID]="a.AttributeID"></app-inline-select>
</span>
```

The included `component` utilizes [Select2](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-select) allowing for a multi-select input field.

This is all working just fine. However, I now need to add a `Save Button` in my parent component that will send some data off to my service. I need the data from this included component though.

During some research, I thought that `ViewChild` may have been an option but this component is on the page multiple times within an `ngFor` loop so it's essentially dynamic not allowing me to call it by name directly which is what `ViewChild` would need.

How could I go about getting data? The save button is unrelated to the included component it self.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

selected is an event not property so you need to wrap it in () not [].
 you can call function that will determine what you need to do when selected event fired.

```
<span *ngIf="inEditMode(r.RuleParentID, a.AttributeID)">
 <app-inline-select (selected)="saveToArray($event)" [source]="fetchSourceList(a.AttributeID)" [ruleParentID]="r.RuleParentID" [attributeID]="a.AttributeID"></app-inline-select>
</span>
```

in component

```
    arrays = []
    saveToArray(a) {
      this.array.push(a);
    }
```

and then

```
   onSave() {
     this.service.save(arrays).then(() => {})
   }
```

there is also [viewChildren](https://netbasal.com/understanding-viewchildren-contentchildren-and-querylist-in-angular-896b0c689f6e) where you will have array of components. So you can loop through every component and get data.

```
  @ViewChildren(InlineSelectComponent) alerts: QueryList<InlineSelectComponent>

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.alerts.forEach(instance => console.log(instance));
  }
```

Comment: `selected` is a property I am passing to the component. Its the list of values that are already selected. Poorly named? Maybe, but it's unrelated to the event you mentioned.

Comment: The only issue I see with this is that lets say I have 10 records on the page. A user could edit more than one record at a time, exposing one or more of the included components. The array that they are then pushed to is not associated with any one specific child in order to know which values belong to which components

Comment: @SBB there is also viewChildren to loop throught child components

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it could work. Trying to implement now and I will let you know

Answer (score 0):

To pass data from a child component back to a parent component you can use an EventEmitter. There was a post that shows how to do it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42109866/7194432

Comment: So how would my parent (Where the save button is) tell the child (the included component) to emit its value back to the parent?

Comment: I suppose that the EventEmitter will be triggered by the childcomponent based on a change event, rather then a click event in the example.