# pass variable from child to parent component when variable changes based on a change event using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, components

I am trying to pass an input value from a select input that has a (change) event associated with it from child component to parent element.
Would like the variable to get updated every time the variable from the child component is updated.

My question is different from [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107167), due to my variable changes on a change event and needs to be updated every time the variable changes.

I was able to figure this out using ViewChild and AfterViewInit but I get an error in the console saying: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: 'Testing'.

Figured there has to be an easy way of doing this. Keep in mind I am still new with Angular.

Child Component template:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Master-Products">Select Master Product</label>
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="pow" (change)="pow = $event.target.value; onKeyUp()" class="form-control" id="Master-Products">
      <option *ngFor="let pow of powers" [value]="pow">{{pow}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Child-component:

```
export class MasterInputComponent {
  powers: any[] = [ 'power1', 'power2', 'power3' ];
  submitted = false;
  pow:string = 'Testing';
  selectedValue = null;
  constructor() { }

  onKeyUp(value): void{
    console.log('Value: ',this.pow);
  }
```

Parent-Component-Template:

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="accessories">
  <h1>ACCESSORIES</h1>
  <h4>Testing: {{power}}</h4>
  <master-input (change)="recieveMessage($event.target.value)"></master-input>
  <accessories></accessories>
```

Parent-Component:

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  @ViewChild(MasterInputComponent) child;
  title = 'Having FUN with Angular';
  posts: any[];
  power:string;

  constructor(private service:ProductsService){}
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.power = this.child.pow;
  }

  recieveMessage(value){
    console.log('Event: ',value);
    this.power = value;
    console.log('Favorite has changed')
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You would want `Output` and an EventEmitter in this case :) https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass data from child to parent component Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107167/pass-data-from-child-to-parent-component-angular2)

Comment: I tried this before my current solution and I got an error as well. I do not remember the error. Both ways work but I still end up with an error in the console. Would you mind showing me an example? Most likely your way is different than how I implemented it.

Comment: I reverted back to when I used the EventEmitter and the error i get is: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined. My app is not broken but i still get that error in console.

Comment: That should work... :) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wga92l?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: I tried your code and I get this error: ERROR TypeError: _co.hasChanged is not a function in my console. plus the value doesn't change next to the word testing on my app and in the example you posted instackblitz. any ideas? Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: I updated my stackblitz a bit, so if you check now, it assigns the value to the variable. Best would be now in this case is that you take the stackblitz, apply your code to it which showcases the error, much easier to help that way :)

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! Will be dissecting your answer for a bit to completely understand what you did.

Comment: You are very welcome! Dissect away :P and come back if you have question :)

Answer (score 0):

do the following steps in your code :

**(ngModelChange)="onKeyUp($event)"** instead of **(change)="pow = $event.target.value; onKeyUp()"**

in your child ts file

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Output() sendMessage = new EventEmitter();

onKeyUp(e) {
    this.sendMessage.next(e);
}
```

parent html

```
<master-input (sendMessage)="recieveMessage($event)"></master-input>
  <accessories></accessories>
```

the following code will add your parent ts

```
recieveMessage(msg) {
    console.log('msg', msg)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
constructor(private service:ProductsService, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){}
ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.power = this.child.pow;
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364880/expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked) will throw light on the exact cause of the issue.

Comment: I actually read this in another article when I typed my error code into google. Did not end up helping me nor did I quite understand the solution.

Comment: The SO link I provided has discussed this issue extensively. And on of the comments in the answer pointed to the same issue that you are facing!

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, I already read that article and did not like the solution as I do not fully understand the reasoning behind it. I am also new to angular and would prefer to understand my code rather than just pasting some answer cause it might make my code work. I have already found an answer to my question in the above comments from @AJT_82. when I have extra time I will dig further into your solution and the making behind it.

Comment: When I go back to try your solution later in the day and find out it works for my situation, I will mark your solution as the answer. Thank you for your time.