# Angular4 @Input() to pass value from parent component to child component

Tags: angular

I have a code in App component.html like this.

```
 <form>
        <input #box1 (blur)="onKey1(box1.value)" type="text" name="username">
        <p>{{box1.value}}</p>
    </form>
```

In AppComponent.ts I have code like this.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent{
    type:string;
    constructor() { }
    onKey1(value:string)
    {
        this.type=value;  
    }
}
```

Now I have created a component named MyComponent3. In that component I want to retrieve the data from app component.The code for MyComponent3.html is as follows:

```
<p>{{type}}</p>
```

In MyComponent3.ts I have the following code.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation,Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-my-component3',
    templateUrl: './my-component3.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-component3.component.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class MyComponent3Component implements OnInit {
    @Input() type;
    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

But in the Output the value is not getting passed from AppComponent to My Component3.

Comment: Where are you actually using Component3?

Comment: That is just to test whether the value is getting passed from parent component to child component. If this works I could use it somewhere else in the program

Comment: How are you using app-my-component3 ?

Comment: By <app-my-component3></app-my-component3> tag.    And this mycomponent3 i am not using anywhere in the program. I used this component to just test wether the input value is getting passed from parent component to child Component.

Comment: Try using it like this <app-my-component3 [type]="type"></app-my-component3>

Comment: Yess!!!!! That helped and resolved my problem. Thank You for the answer. And Could you please tell me why we have to mention that in component3 tag.

Comment: HI. I notice your ```import``` path is ```@angular/core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks``` instead of ```@angular/core```, my auto imports in VSCode are doing the same thing. I wonder why this is!! ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever attribute you want to pass to child component should be mentioned in it. You can pass to the child component using @input and the html as follows,

```
<app-my-component3 [type]="type"></app-my-component3>
```

Comment: Could you also tell me how to pass a value from child component to parent Component.

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107167/pass-data-from-child-to-parent-component-angular2