# Access constant in child component from Parent component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two components, I want to print the text in child component from the parent on click.

Parent Component :

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'parent',
templateUrl: 'parent.html'
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
   @ViewChild(ChildComponent) child;

   constructor() {
   }

   ngOnInit() {
   }

   click(){
       console.log(this.child.text);
   }
}
```

Child Component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'child',
templateUrl: 'child.html'
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor() {
   }

   ngOnInit() {
       const text = 'TEXT HERE';
   }

   //Some code...
}
```

I am new to angular. Just want to know how to make it work, I want some constants to be in one point and shared by others. Not necessary the constants has to be in child component only. Just need a good suggestion on how to make it work with a good coding strategy

This is not working for me.

Thanks

Comment: post your template of parent component and you need to use @input

Comment: You should use `@Output` refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107167/pass-data-from-child-to-parent-component-angular2

Answer (score 1):

my solution is creating a sharedService between these two component

```
/// SharedService


export class SharedService {
   sharedConst: string = 'blabla';
}


//// ParentComponent


@Component({
    ...,
    providers: [SharedService]
})

export class ParentComponent {
    constructor(private sharedService: SharedService){}
}

//// ChildComponent

@Component({
    ...,
    template: `{{sharedService.sharedConst}}`
})

export class ChildComponent {


   constructor(public sharedService: SharedService){}
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but just want to know if this is a good idea in my case.
In my huge application, I have only 3 constants string that I want to share withing only two components. Is it okay to make a complete new service just for this much ?? I am new... I just want to know

Comment: I think yes it's a good idea because if you want to use these constant after that not only in those two component but also in more other components this will not cost you any changes in the future

Comment: True .. How about I just make a class, keep the constants there and import the class everywhere needed instead of making a service... I am not denying your solution. Just trying to get into depth.. I hardly have anyidea about angular

Comment: it's a good solution too if you will make it only for declaring some constants and it's better than my solution

Comment: I got some confidence from your reply. Thanks Khaled.. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

`text`is a local variable of the `ngOnInit` method. It only exists in that method, and disappears when this method exists. You need to make it an instance field of the ChildComponent class:

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
   text: string;

   ngOnInit() {
       this.text = 'TEXT HERE';
   }
}
```

Comment: yes I tried this, but was not accessible from parent component. It says child is undefined when it is trying to print

Comment: Then it means that the parent template doesn't contain any child component.

Comment: it does. When I run the application, it showing the child component. but when I try to access one of its constant from parent.. using  @ViewChild, it is not working

Comment: We can't help if you don't post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.