# how to set prop child to parent in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I work on the team who using Angular, I was using Vue before, I have learned the Angular 7 so far for 5 days, and my team still using Angular 4, I want to know how to set up the prop in child to parent? I usually in Vue use Prop in components so, I can use it on other component and set the data of Prop, but in Angular, I don't know how to use it  (thought I have learned it so far and still not sure how to binding in the correct way) and is it possible ??

I want to make a loader component in this Angular component, but I want to make it reusable to set up the width and height of the loader on another component, how to do this in Angular ??

let say I want to fetch data and then wait for it while showing a loader

like this :

```
<div>
   <app-loader *ngIf="show == 'true'" [setupWidhtLoader]="is-That-Possible-to-Set-Up-Here?"> </app-loader>
   <h2> {{ data.full_name  }} </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you may be looking for the `Output` binding

Comment: should i use it on loader component? any example ? @ExplosionPills

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass data from child to parent component Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107167/pass-data-from-child-to-parent-component-angular2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass data from the child component to the parent via an event, use the `@Output()` decorator.  See [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event) for more details.  An example is shown below:

Parent HTML component:

```
<app-loader (dataChange)="handleDataChange($event)"></app-loader>
```

Parent TS component:

```
public handleDataChange(event){
  //Do something here
}
```

Child TS component:

```
@Output()
public dataChange:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

You can also pass data back and forth between the parent and child component using two-way binding.  When the value is changed in one location, it will automatically be changed in the other.  Syntax is as follows:

```
<app-loader [(width)]="parentWidth"></app-loader>
```

Where `parentWidth` is a property on the parent and `width` is a property on the child decorated with `@Input()` and `widthChange` is an `EventEmitter` property of the child decorated with `@Output()`.

If you want to share data between these two components and potentially others, you can create a shared service.  This is probably a little overkill for your situation.

Comment: i see that, now i get some error, i want to use that child component in my current component, it not going trigger :(