# call another component2 function from component1 html page itself

Tags: angular, components

I have a 2 components "Home" and "Permissions".
In my Home.html page I created a bootstrap modal with "OK" and "CANCEL" buttons.
"OK" need to call the function "deleteRecord()" that belongs to the "Permissions" component.

In this, "Home" is a parent route and "Permissions" is a child route

```
{
path: 'fis', component: HomeComponent,
children: [
  { path: 'Permissions', component: Permissions},
]
}
```

Could any one suggest me how to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38974896/call-child-component-method-from-parent-class-angular'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call child component method from parent class - Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38974896/call-child-component-method-from-parent-class-angular)

Comment: Hi swetansh kumar
actually currently i'm using it single component so the way like importing the child component and calling will work
but like this i need to use in several coponents
i have 10 components each component have a function "deleteRecord()".
so it won't work for me

Comment: Did you try creating an interface for your components ?

Comment: no i didn't created interface for the components, could you let me know how to do this in angular2

Comment: @Manikanta why are using the different component when you can do this thing using a single component itself? make the method in the same component itself and call it

Comment: i want to make a reusable model popup for delete record. I have a  multiple page with list record like users, roles, posts, notification, so created a multiple components for each item. any item in  those record can be deleted, so i'm giving a reusable model for delete confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a `IDeleteRecordComponent`

```
export interface IDeleteRecordComponent{
    deleteRecords();
}
```

and make your `PermissionsComponent` (and the other 10 components) implement it. Then, from the `HomeComponent`, use `@ViewChild` to access these and call teir methods :

**permissions.component.ts**

```
export class PermissionsComponent implements IDeleteRecords{
    deleteRecords(){
       // implement records deletion
    }
}
```

**home.component.ts**

```
export class HomeComponent {
     @ViewChild("permissions") permissionsComponent: IDeleteRecords;

     deleteRecords(){
         this.permissionsComponent.deleteRecords();
     }
}
```

**home.component.html**

```
<button (click)="deleteRecords()">OK</button>
```

Comment: Hi, Here is a one problem

deleteRecords(){
         this.permissionsComponent.deleteRecords();
     }
this is for calling the deleteRecords in the permissionsComponent,
if i want to call to deleteRecords in the rolesComponent,
i need to again use one more line.
So i want the code like 
the deleteRecords function should be in child component itself but when i clicking the OK from the roles page it need to call the deleteRecords in the rolesComponent. like this i'm expecting

Comment: So you want to call deleteRecords functions in all of you child components at the same time?

Comment: no the deleteRecords  need to call currently active component. for example i have roles and permissions child. Currently i'm in the roles child, the deleteRecords  with in the child need to call