# Angular: How to use template reference variable for calling child method?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to call a method from a parent component to child component using template reference variable.. I tried it like below,

navigation.component.html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary relative waves-light" (click)="CartTable.loadCart()" mdbWavesEffect>My Cart</button>

<app-cart-table-modal #CartTable></app-cart-table-modal>
```

cart-table-modal.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-cart-table-modal',
  templateUrl: './cart-table-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cart-table-modal.component.scss']
})
export class CartTableModalComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {   }

loadCart(){
 console.log('load cart called');
}
}
```

But I am getting an error as

> ERROR TypeError: jit_nodeValue_5(...).loadCart is not a function

Please let me know, how to fix this error.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vjbf4s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html. Post a complete minimal example (as I just did) reproducing the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call child component method from parent class - Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38974896/call-child-component-method-from-parent-class-angular)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call public method from a child component via `@ViewChild()` decorator.

**child.component.ts**

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {   }

  method1(){
    console.log('logged me!');
  }

}
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<div>
    <button (click)="onLogged()">Logged Me!</button>
    <child-comp #childComp></child-comp>
</div>
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) child_component: ChildComponent;

  constructor() {   }

  onLogged(){
    this.child_component.method1();
  }

}
```

Read more about Component interaction in [angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction).