# How to call child components's method from the parent component in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

> Parent Component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent }  from './notify.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template:
    `
    <button (click)="submit()">Call Child Component Method</button>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private childComp: ChildComponent) { 
    }

    submit(): void {
        // execute child component method
        // This line is compiled properly but at the run time it gives me error related to the static injector## Heading ##
        childComp.callMethod();
    }
}
```

> Child component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    template: '<h3>Child component {{test}}</h3>'
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
   test:string; 
   constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }

    callMethod(): void {
        console.log('successfully executed.');
        this.test = 'Me';
    }
}
```

I am getting an error for the static injector, I am not able to inject the child component in the parent component. Here is the error.

> StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AppComponent -> ChildComponent]:
>   StaticInjectorError[ChildComponet]: 
>           NullInjectorError: No provider for ChildComponet!

I have added the reference in the Appmodule and added the component in the declaration. Still, I am facing the same issue.

Please Help!!

Comment: Use @ViewChild have a look at https://alligator.io/angular/viewchild-access-component/

Comment: @Vikas I have used the same but I am getting this issue "Declaration expected". An error is coming when I try to write @ViewChild('child') child:ChildCmp;in the component. Please help!

Comment: `@ViewChild('child') child:ChildCmp;` Where is your type `ChildCmp`?? I see `ChildComponent` not `ChildCmp`.

Comment: @Developer use rx js Subject. You can try my approach. Creating instance of a component is not a recommended approach

Comment: @penleychan yes its ChildComponent its typo from me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> **Update:**
>
> just export the child like `<app-child #child></app-child>` and then
>   you can call all methods using `child` like : `<button> (click)="child.callMethod()">Call</button>`
>
> **Parent.html**
>
> ```
> <app-child #child></app-child>
> <button (click)="child.callMethod()">Call</button>
> ```

**Old answer**

You can use `@ViewChild` by Parent like in example:

**Parent**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from './child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() { }
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) private myChild: ChildComponent;
  submit() {
    this.myChild.callMethod();
  }
}
```

**Child:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `<h3>Child component {{test}}</h3>`
})
export class ChildComponent {
  test = 0;
  callMethod() {
    console.log('successfully executed.');
    this.test++;
  }
}
```

**[Here is a worked example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-call-child-componentss-method-from-the-parent-component)**

Comment: I want to call the method of the child component, My requirement is such like if a value of variable changes or it remains the same a particular function from the child should call which will return me data from the service.

Comment: OnSubmit you can just change the input and your method will be called

Comment: My value remains the same, In that case the Onchange lifecycle hook won't be called.O r there any lifecycle hook available for the same? (Value change or remains the same the function should call) and I am calling this function from the parent component's function.

Comment: I have already two components available and want to communicate between those only. can't create a shared service for the same. As I have to do a service call from the child component's method. All are predefined just want to call the function in the child

Comment: @ViewChild(ChildComponent) private myChild: ChildComponent; I am getting this error  "error TS1146: Declaration expected." Getting red squiggly under the private.

Comment: Try just: `@ViewChild(ChildComponent) myChild;`

Comment: Already tried that the squiggly moves to myChild and the message remains the same :(

Comment: Send me your new code! This seems to be a semicolon  problem

Comment: This worked !!! I just need to move the line in the general declaration area, I had placed that line in the private function. Dumb me, Thanks for the help !!

Comment: Awesome!, this is what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Guys follow this link [gist.github.com/pradipkumardesai/… to get a small and right implementation that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by introducing a concept called @Viewchild
which allows allows a one component to be injected into another, giving the parent access to its attributes and functions.

for example:

## Parent component

```
   import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
   import { ChildComponent } from "../child/child.component";
    @Component({
    selector: 'app-parent',
    template: `
    Message: {{ message }}
 <app-child></app-child>
    `,styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
    })
    export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {

@ViewChild(ChildComponent) child;

constructor() { }

message:string;

ngAfterViewInit() {
this.message = this.child.message
  }
 }
```

## child component

```
    import { Component} from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
    selector: 'app-child',
    template: `
    `,
    styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
    })
    export class ChildComponent {
    message = 'Hola Mundo!';
    constructor() { }
  }
```

Comment: i am getting this error "error TS1146: Declaration expected."  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) child; And getting red squiggly under the child.

Comment: please add this below statement   
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **ChildComponent** under declarations on app.module.ts

Comment: i am getting this error "error TS1146: Declaration expected." @ViewChild(ChildComponent) child; And getting red squiggly under the child.