# How to call a component from other component in angular 7

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a checkbox,if that checkbox is checked, I need to show alert message on load the application.But problem is that checkbox is in header component and it is linked with home component.So when I will be in home page and if that checkbox is checked, I need to show alert message on load the application. Here is the code below,

### header.component.html

```html
<div><input checked type="checkbox">Other-component</div>
```

### header.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router }  from "@angular/router";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-header',
    templateUrl: './header.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public router: Router){} 

    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

### home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import Speech from 'speak-tts';
import { RxSpeechRecognitionService, resultList, } from '@kamiazya/ngx-speech-recognition';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],  
    providers: [ RxSpeechRecognitionService ]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {  
    showit:any;
    nestedjson:any;
    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,public service: RxSpeechRecognitionService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    } 
}
```

Comment: You use a [service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)

Comment: Use DI (Dependency Injecrion) In angular thay have name `services`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call child components's method from the parent component in Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53057340/how-to-call-child-componentss-method-from-the-parent-component-in-angular-6)

Answer (score 1):

## 1) To the question in your headline: How to call a component from other component

You can give the header component a reference id inside the home template.

```
<app-header #header></app-header>
```

Then you can access the header component through a ViewChild in your home component.

```
@ViewChild('header') headerComponent: HeaderComponent;
```

But this does not seem to be very good practice for your needs. Consider using a service and subscribe to a Subject by using RxJs Observables. Or much simpler in your case: just use two-way-data-binding.

## 2) The way you should actually communicate between components: two way data binding

**header.component.ts**

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() isChecked: boolean;
  @Output() isCheckedChanged = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor(public router: Router){} 

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**header.component.html**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="isChecked" type="checkbox">
```

**home.component.ts**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  isChecked: boolean;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  } 
}
```

**home.component.html**

```
<app-header [(isChecked)]="isChecked"></app-header>
```

Edit: in your case you also don't need two way binding since you don't need any feedback from the HeaderComponent. One way data binding will be fine. Then you can **remove** the line

```
@Output() isCheckedChanged = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
```

And in Home template don't use banana in the box syntax [()], instead just use []:

```
<app-header [isChecked]="isChecked"></app-header>
```

Comment: I am getting this error Can't bind to 'isChecked' since it isn't a known property of 'app-header'.
1. If 'app-header' is an Angular component and it has 'isChecked' input, then verify that it is part of this module.

Comment: Do you want to have HeaderComponent rendered inside HomeComponent or vice versa? If the first one, than you need to define the property isChecked as @Input() inside HeaderComponent.

Comment: First one, I added and checkbox is showing now in home page but  not getting alert onload when it is by default checked

Comment: Can you show us more code? In which component do you call the alert? Please notice that HomeComponent only gets the value of your checkbox inside HeaderComponent when you also implement the @Output() inside the HeaderComponent and use the name convention <your-input-property-name>Changed - in your example 'isCheckedChanged'. Also you must call this.isCheckedChanged.emit(this.isChecked) to notify that your Output changed. Then you can use the banana in the box syntax [(isChecked)]="isChecked" in your HomeComponent template and your isChecked property of your HomeComponent will change, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a service which is defined at the root level.And then with the help of a service you can either emit or use Subjects to capture in your home component.