# Sending output from child component to parent Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to send live text to my parent component from my child in order to filter some output as the user types. The console output is the object which does update as I type, but it is being fired from the child component. However the parent component method that has the variable from the child is not firing which is where I need to to implement a pipe to filter comments.

Child component

```
 @Output() filterEmiter = new EventEmitter<FilterModel>();

    constructor(service: CommentsFilterService) { }

    passFilterToCommentsComponent() {
        console.log(this);
        this.filterEmiter.emit(this.filter)
    }
```

Child component html

```
<input name="Customer ID" [ngModel]="filter.customerId" (ngModelChange)="filter.customerId = $event"  (ngModelChange)="passFilterToCommentsComponent()">
```

Parent component

```
  @Input() filter: FilterModel;

    constructor(service: CommentsService) {
        this.tabs = service.getLongtabs();
    }

    filterReviews() {
        console.log("HIT HIT HIT")
    }
```

parent component html file

```
<proto-approval (filterEmiter)="filterReviews()"></proto-approval>
```

The desired output would be `"HIT HIT HIT"` as I type showing me the method is in fact being fired. The second would be for the `filter` object to be passed and updated so a pipe can be implemented.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call child components's method from the parent component in Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53057340/how-to-call-child-componentss-method-from-the-parent-component-in-angular-6)

Comment: @Ferhado not really I just updated my question

Answer (score 3):

you don't need `@ViewChild` here. just subscribe to `filterEmiter` in the template like this:

```
<proto-approval (filterEmiter)="filterReviews($event)">
```

```
filterReviews($event){
    this.filter = $event
}
```

Comment: am I right that now problem is not in communication between components, but in child getting events from its template?

Comment: try using banana in the box syntax for ngModel  [(ngModel)]="filter?.erpNumber". It "to way binds" the value of erpNumber to inputs value instead of [] = one way binding

Comment: (ngModelChange)="filter.erpNumber = $event;passFilterToCommentsComponent()" to update the value before reacting to event. leave [ngModel] as it was in single brackets

Comment: I updated my question and found a solution for the previous issue. Have a look if you'd like,