# Access outer component instance from directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-components

I have a simple component with a single input [id], and a template that uses 'my-directive'.

```
<div>
    <div my-directive>
        hello world
    </div>
</div>
```

simple-component would be used multiple times in a template:

```
<simple-component [id]="1"></simple-component>
<simple-component [id]="2"></simple-component>
```

Is it possible for me to **access the instance of simple-component from within each my-directive instance?**

The goal is that each my-directive instance knows their simple-component 'host/outer' instance,
as so to access their 'id' property, for example.

Comment: Check my example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53057340/how-to-call-child-componentss-method-from-the-parent-component-in-angular-6/53057589#53057589

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way of accessing parent component using `@Host()` resolution modifier (more info on [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#resolution-modifiers)). The basic idea is to navigate the component tree by using Dependency Injection in order to find a reference to a parent element from the child element. There are a couple of nice examples [here](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-navtree).

By default, Angular searches for provided instance upwards all the way to the `NullInjector` (the highest in the hierarchy). If it doesn't find the instance it it throws the exception unless we use `@Optional`, in that case it returns `null`. 
In your specific example, we use `Host()` to tell Angular to stop searching with this component as the last stop when searching. We don't have to use it, even if we omit the `Host()` it will still work.

In `my-directive.directive.ts` file:

```js
constructor(@Host() private parent: SimpleComponent) {
    // here we have an instance of SimpleComponent and we can access its properties except for the Input properties, those are still not set in constructor
}
```

I have created a simple [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vupfq4) example demonstrating this.

**EDIT**: Here is the [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x5eaom) where we find the instance of `AppComponent` that is a parent of `SimpleComponent` from the *directive*. Here we cannot use `Host()` since the search will stop with the directive as the last stop (and `AppComponent` is higher up in the chain). So we just don't add anything and we get the correct reference.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using a service:

```
@Injectable()
export class IdsTrackerService {
  private ids$$: BehaviorSubject<{ [key: string]: true }> = new BehaviorSubject(
    {}
  );
  public ids$: Observable<string[]> = this.ids$$
    .asObservable()
    .pipe(map(ids => Object.keys(ids)));

  public addId(id: string): void {
    if (!this.ids$$.value[id]) {
      this.ids$$.next({
        ...this.ids$$.value,
        [id]: true
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Then within your directive you'd just have to register an ID when the directive is created and unregister it when destroyed:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[appTrackId]"
})
export class TrackIdDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() appTrackId: string | undefined;

  constructor(private idsTrackerService: IdsTrackerService) {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    if (!this.appTrackId) {
      throw new Error(`When using "appTrackId" please pass the ID as argument`);
    }

    this.idsTrackerService.addId(this.appTrackId);

    // you now also have access to
    // this.idsTrackerService.ids$ :) !
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.idsTrackerService.removeId(this.appTrackId);
  }
}
```

Don't forget to provide the service **on a component level** rather than module level or globally:

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
  // declare the provider on a component basis
  // so you get a different instance of the service per component
  providers: [IdsTrackerService]
})
```

**Here's a live demo with a debug view to display the registered IDs: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jyvezk**