# Angular - Material Component Mat-Step

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I'm having a problem accessing a method from another child component.
I need this method to do a validation on a form.
When I start the registration all the constructors are called but when I save a record and I try to recover this value saved in localStorage I can't.
How should I solve the problem to be able to access the ngOnInit method or another method that can retrieve the values ​​saved in localStorage

Component.html

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper [linear]="true">

  <mat-step [stepControl]="form" [optional]="isOptional">
    
  <ng-template matStepLabel>Form One</ng-template>

  <app-form
          [stepper]="stepper">
  </app-form>

  </mat-step>

  <mat-step [stepControl]="formT" [optional]="isOptional">
    
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Arma</ng-template>
  
  <app-formT
            [stepper]="stepper">
    </app-formT>
  
    </mat-step>

</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Component

```
export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {

    isOptional: boolean;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.isOptional = false;
    }

    stepChanged(stepper){
        stepper.selected.interacted = false;
    }

}
```

Form1.component

```
export class Form1Component implements OnInit {

    @Input() stepper: any;

    private save(stepper: any) {
        this.dadosArmaService.save(frm).subscribe(() => {
            localStorage.setItem("objext", JSON.stringify(object));
            stepper.next();
        }, (e) => {
            console.log(e);
        });
    }
```

Form2.Component

```
export class Form2Component implements OnInit {
    @Input() stepper: any;
    
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.stepper._getIndicatorType = () => 'number';
    }

    constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    ) {
        
        const objectSave = localStorage.getItem('obj);

        if(armaSalva !== null) {
            this.isCheck = true; //Value form
        } else {
            this.isCheck = false;
        }

     }

    ngOnInit() {
        if(armaSalva !== null) {
            this.isCheck = true;
        } else {
            this.isCheck = false;
        }
    }

}
```

html

```
<div fxLayout="row">
      <div fxFlex="50%" *ngIf="!isCheck">
        <mat-checkbox formControlName="check">
            <strong>NOT</strong> <mat-label>Change </mat-label>
        </mat-checkbox>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the updated value from localStorage in Form2 after you click next from Form1?

Comment: yes when I click on save the stepper.next() command and triggered but I can't retrieve the value in tab 2 saved in localstorage to do a check with if

Comment: I posted an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the hashTag (#) to export component Reference and using @Input to get the Reference in Other Component Like in Example:

```html
    <app-form [stepper]="stepper" #form1></app-form>
    
    <app-formT [stepper]="stepper" [form1Ref]="form1"></app-formT>
```

I have commented the changes with //--------------

```js
    export class Form1Component implements OnInit {
    
      @Input() stepper: any;
    
      @Input() form1Ref: any; //--------------
    
      callMethodFromForm1() { //--------------
        this.form1.ngOnInit();
      }
    
      private save(stepper: any) {
        this.dadosArmaService.save(frm).subscribe(() => {
          localStorage.setItem("objext", JSON.stringify(object));
          stepper.next();
        }, (e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    
      }
```

Check this example: [How to call child components's method from the parent component in Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53057340/how-to-call-child-componentss-method-from-the-parent-component-in-angular-6/53057589#53057589)

Answer (score 0):

To rephrase your question. What you actually want is when you click save, which triggers the `save` function in `form1`, you need away to update the `isCheck` in `form2`.

---

The reason why your code failed to update the `isCheck` property in `form2` is that you do it in the `constructor` and `ngOnInit`.

These two only got called once. The `constructor` got called first, then the `ngOnInit`.

---

To solve that, you need the `mat-stepper` to broadcast the selection change using the `selectionChange` output.

I haven't tested this, but this should solve your problem.

##### app.component.html

```html
<mat-stepper (selectionChange)="notifyForm2($event)">

  <mat-step [stepControl]="form1">
    <app-form1></app-form1>
  </mat-step>

  <mat-step [stepControl]="form2">
     <app-form2></app-form2>
  </mat-step>

</mat-stepper>
```

##### app.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

  @viewChild(form2Component) // access the form2Component here.
  public form2: !form2Component;
  
  public notifyForm2(event: StepperSelectionEvent) {
    
    const savedValue = localStorage.getItem('SAVED-VALUE');

    if(savedValue !== null)
      this.form2.isClick = true;
    else
      this.form2.isClick = false;
  }
}
```

##### form2.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app.form2',
  templateUrl: './form2.component.html'
})
export class Form2Component {
  
  public isClick = false;
}
```