# How do I trigger child function from parent component with event

Tags: angular, viewchild

I have a function on click event at parent html.

```
<span (click)="onFilterClick()" class="filter-icon">
<mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon></span>
<m-scp-filter-template [openFilter]="true" *ngIf="templateFor === 'col1' "></m-scp-filter-template>
```

child component at parent ts

```
@ViewChild(ScpFilterTemplateComponent) myChild;
```

the function at parent ts

```
onFilterClick() {
  this.myChild.openMenu();
}
```

and called function at child ts

```
openMenu() {
     console.log('successfully executed.');
}
```

but I getting error

> 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'openMenu' of undefined
>       at ScpDataTableComponent.'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call child component method from parent class - Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38974896/call-child-component-method-from-parent-class-angular)

Comment: @TusharWalzade I don't want to use ngAfterViewInit. Only click trigger

Comment: Simply try to update your property with type as `@ViewChild(ScpFilterTemplateComponent) myChild: ScpFilterTemplateComponent;`

Comment: Is the component visible? because since you are using *ngIf it may be removed from the DOM

Comment: you have ngIf in template, are you sure ScpFilterTemplateComponentis is visible?

Comment: @TusharWalzade still same error

Comment: @yannick, ABOS hi, my click event on span and it's visible.

Comment: @wekabird, can you remove `*ngIf="templateFor === 'col1' "` temporarily to narrow down the issue?

Comment: @ABOS yes, it's worked. But why?

Comment: Then the condition in your ngIf wasn't true, so it was removed from the DOM.

Comment: @wekabird, can you try my answer below?

Comment: @ABOS thanks again. I don't use a Timeout. If I found the answer,  I am going to share.

Answer (score 1):

> - As `@ViewChild` refers to the existing child view/ selector, your ***child view needs to exist in the parent HTML***. If your `*ngIf` returns *false*, Angular won't even create a child view in the parent HTML. So your **`myChild`** itself **would be *undefined*** in that case & you won't be able to access any methods/ properties further.
> - There is an alternate bypass too - that you can create an instance of your child class & call the method, but ***it's not recommended***.

***[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gvgvke?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)***'s the minimal reproduction of both the scenarios.

Comment: this is not the same issue

Comment: nope, ngIf might be causing the issue which is missing in your demo, so OP might need to wrap `this.myChild.openMenu();` inside a timeout etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a copy from the Angular documentation https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild

```
import { AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Component }                from '@angular/core';
import { CountdownTimerComponent }  from './countdown-timer.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-countdown-parent-vc',
  template: `
  <h3>Countdown to Liftoff (via ViewChild)</h3>
  <button (click)="start()">Start</button>
  <button (click)="stop()">Stop</button>
  <div class="seconds">{{ seconds() }}</div>
  <app-countdown-timer></app-countdown-timer>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['../assets/demo.css']
})
export class CountdownViewChildParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild(CountdownTimerComponent)
  private timerComponent: CountdownTimerComponent;

  seconds() { return 0; }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Redefine `seconds()` to get from the `CountdownTimerComponent.seconds` ...
    // but wait a tick first to avoid one-time devMode
    // unidirectional-data-flow-violation error
    setTimeout(() => this.seconds = () => this.timerComponent.seconds, 0);
  }

  start() { this.timerComponent.start(); }
  stop() { this.timerComponent.stop(); }
}
```

In the example the `start()` and `stop()` method call a the respective methods of the child component when the buttons of the parent component are clicked

---

If the child component has a *ngIf set onto it you can probably fix it by
[Angular 2 @ViewChild in *ngIf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366981/angular-2-viewchild-in-ngif)

Comment: thanks, I'm looking for triggered function with event

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with a setter?

```
@ViewChild(ScpFilterTemplateComponent) 
set _myChild(v) {
  setTimeout(() => { this.myChild= v; }, 0);
}
```

or wrap `this.myChild.openMenu();` inside a timeout etc

Answer (score 0):

try making that child method public...

```
public openMenu() {
     console.log('successfully executed.');
}
```