# Can't read variable in component's html file in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to display an array's data (populated in `chat.component`)..

```
public matchesList = [];

loadMatches() {
...
    if (result.success) {
      this.matchesList = result.matches_list.split(',');
      console.log(this.matchesList);
    }
}
```

..in `chat.component.html`..

```
<div class="matchesList" *ngFor="let match of matchesList">
    <p>{{match}}</p>
</div>
```

.. without any luck!

The `console.log()` shows me that the array is populated correctly: `(3) ["3", "5", "6"]`.

`loadMatches()` is called from another component `home.component`..

```
import { ChatComponent } from '../chat/chat.component';

@Component({
  providers: [ChatComponent],
  ...
})

loadChatViewData() {
    this.chatComp.loadMatches();
}
<a class="nav-link" (click)="loadChatViewData()"></a>
```

Why isn't `matchesList`'s data accessible in `chat.component.html` ?

Thank you!

Comment: That is not how you use components, you don't need to add it to the components `providers:[...]`. That is used for services.

Comment: @marshalllegend Thanks for your answer, what can I do?

Comment: The answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38974896/call-child-component-method-from-parent-class-angular) should help clarify how to call a method in a child component.

Comment: @marshalllegend Thanks a lot! It works fine now, I need to get my head into more documentation! Thanks again

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it!

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the instance which you use to call `this.chatComp.loadMatches()` is not the same as the one which was used for the rendering following template -

```
chat.component.html

<div class="matchesList" *ngFor="let match of matchesList">
    <p>{{match}}</p>
</div>
```

You have used `providers: [ChatComponent]` which will give you a different instance as compared to the one used for rendering.

We will be able to help you further if you can share your html/.ts files for the following components and also the code [html] which places the component in your UI -

```
1. Chat Component.ts/.html
2. Home component.ts/.html
3. The parent [if any] which holds those two components [If not then let us know how those are rendered [i.e. Parent/Child?]
```