# No access to child component

Tags: angular, viewchild

I have 2 components. The first `app-aaa` has`app-bbb` inside.

aaa-component.html:

```
        <button (click)="clickMe(flight)" type="submit">click me</button>           
        <app-bbb [flight]="flight"></app-bbb>
```

aaa-component.ts:

```
        export class AaaComponent implements OnInit {

            @ViewChild(BbbComponent) change: BbbComponent;

            constructor(){}

            ngOnInit() {
                flight: ModelFlights = {
                    name:''
                    value:''
                }
            }             

            clickMe(form) {           
                this.change.change();
            }
        }
```

bbb-component.ts:

```
     export class BbbComponent implements OnInit {
          @Input() flight: ModelFlights; 
          constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef, private  sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private renderer2: Renderer2,
                      @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document) {}
          ngOnInit(){}
          change() {
            console.log('change event ');
            // ...    
          }
        }
```

I want to make access to the method from the `bbb-component` component by clicking the `clickMe` button

currently receiving error message:

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property `change` of undefined
    at AaaComponent.push../src/app/core/aaa/aaa.component.ts.AaaComponent.clickMe

line:  this.change.change();

I have such libraries:

```
    {
        "name": "weco-travel-app",
        "version": "0.0.0",
        "scripts": {
            "ng": "ng",
            "start": "ng serve",
            "build": "ng build",
            "test": "ng test",
            "lint": "ng lint",
            "e2e": "ng e2e",
            "scss": "node-sass --watch assets/scss -o assets/css"
        },
        "private": true,
        "dependencies": {
            "@angular/animations": "^7.2.15",
            "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
            "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
            "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
            "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
            "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
            "@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
            "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^8.0.2",
            "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
            "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
            "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
            "@angular/service-worker": "^8.0.0",
            "animate": "^1.0.0",
            "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
            "core-js": "^2.5.4",
            "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
            "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
            "jquery": "^3.4.1",
            "moment": "^2.24.0",
            "ng-connection-service": "^1.0.4",
            "ng-recaptcha": "^4.3.0",
            "ngx-owl-carousel": "2.0.5",
            "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
            "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
            "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.1",
            "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
            "tslib": "^1.9.0",
            "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
        },
        "devDependencies": {
            "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
            "@angular/cli": "~7.3.9",
            "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
            "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
            "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
            "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
            "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
            "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
            "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
            "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
            "karma": "~4.0.0",
            "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
            "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
            "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
            "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
            "protractor": "~5.4.0",
            "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
            "tslint": "~5.11.0",
            "typescript": "~3.2.2",
            "webpack": "^4.32.1",
            "webpack-dev-server": "^3.4.1"
        },
        "description": "This project was generated with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) version 7.3.9.",
        "main": "index.js",
        "author": "",
        "license": "ISC"
    }
```

Please help

Comment: The problem is that it cannot identify the this.change (it is undefined at the moment of calling). Can you make sure that your ViewChild is configured properly by checking the component name?

Comment: Also, look at this answer for the string selector [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38974968/6686446)

Comment: the `bbb-component` has such a constructor `constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private renderer2: Renderer2,
              @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document) {}` I don't know how to create such an object : `notifyObj = new BbbComponent();`

Answer (score 0):

You need change your html to:

```
...
        <app-bbb #test [flight]="flight"></app-bbb>
...
```

And your component to:

```
...
            @ViewChild("test", {static: false}) change: BbbComponent;
...
```

I build a sample for you:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zdmaft?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: but my component looks like this: `export class ResultOfFlightsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() flight: ModelFlights; 
  constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef, private  sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private renderer2: Renderer2,
              @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {}
  change() {
    console.log('change event ');
 // ...    
  }
}` I still have a error: `Cannot read property 'changeUrl' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next`

Comment: I update the sample:
app.component2 is now your ResultOfFlightsComponent. 
And it's ok.

where's the property 'changeUrl'? i need more code to help you

Comment: `export class BbbComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() flight: ModelFlights; 
  constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef, private  sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private renderer2: Renderer2,
              @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {}
  change() {
    console.log('change event ');
 // ...    
  }
}` Error:  `Cannot read property change of undefined at SafeSubscriber._next

Comment: is the same code as the previous message, just the component name is different

Comment: this is the current code: `export class BbbComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() flight: ModelFlights; 
  constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef, private  sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private renderer2: Renderer2,
              @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document) {}
  ngOnInit(){}
  change() {
    console.log('change event ');
 // ...    
  } }` receives an error message: `Cannot read property 'change' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next

Comment: I have such libraries. I wrote them in a post