# Angular: When inspecting child component, I don't see all methods, only @Input and @Output

Tags: angular, angular-components, viewchild

In my Angular app I have a component called `Component1` with selector `component-1`, and it's template contains a nested instance of itself:

`<div>
  <component-1></component-1>
</div>`

So the **parent** `Component1` contains a **child** `Component1`.

**My Goal:**

`Component1` contains a method `method1()`. I want to call the child component's `method1` from the parent component. Something like `this.child.method1()`.

**What I've Tried:**

In the component I get `child` with the following code: `@ViewChild(Component1) child: Component1;`. If I do `console.log(this.child)` I get an object that contains all the `@Input` and `@Output` values from `Component1`, but not the methods like `method1()`.

**What I Want To Know:**

How do I access `this.child.method1()`?

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest not trying to invoke the child method in the parent. Consider rethinking the architecture and the data flow of your app. You would want it to be the other way round, calling a method in the parent from a child using an event emitter to communicate https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event.

Parent Component:

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
    .....
    onExecute() {
        // Execute some code
    }
}
```

Child Component

```
@Component({
   selector: 'child-component',
   templateUrl: './child-component.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./child-component.component.scss']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() execute = new EventEmitter();
    .....
    someMethod() {
        this.execute.emit(); // you can send any variable to parent
    }
}
```

When `this.execute.emit();` is fired, your handler in your parent element (`onExecute`) will be called.

Here is a stackblitz [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1h1rdz)

Answer (score 0):

I dont really get why you want to do that. Usually there is a necessity to call parent method from child, like closing a modal, etc. But check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/38974968/7393630. It might help what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Are you tried with public methods in child component.

```
export class HelloComponent  {

  @Input() name: string;
  public method1() {
    console.log('yes It iss called');
  }

}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i55bbe