# How to call a method in a child component from a parent component?

Tags: angular

Okay the title may be a little confusing. My child component is in its own module and is using services that aren't available to the parent component.

I want to change some values in the child component on click of a button and was messing around and set something up like this.

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-parent-component'
 template: `
 <button (click)="refreshData()" />
 <app-child-component> </app-child-component>
`
})
export class ParentComponent{
 refreshData() {
   ChildComponent.runRefresh()
 }
}

@Component({
 selector: 'app-child-component'
 template: ``
})
export class ChildComponent{
 static runRefresh() {
   console.log('refreshing')
   // Do things involving data on a service scoped to this component/module
 }
}
```

I was curious if there was something inherently wrong with this approach?  Are there better ways to solve the problem.  Im familiar with checking for the changes in NgOnChanges event.

I guess what i'm trying to do is call a method inside of the child component, that uses the child component resources on a scoped service, from a parent component.

Edit: Also aware of using @ViewChild and not making the child components method static. Maybe that is the only "right" way?

Comment: Only one I can think of is if you have multiple instances of the component, which of the components are you going to refresh?

I think I would rather go for the component having its own way of triggering a refresh through a @Input setter or some other way.

Comment: @IngeOlaisen refreshing is more of a refresh of the data and make a call to the api. Not actually refreshing anything in the browser. I know I can use an ViewChild and put a reference on the <app-child-component #childReference >.  Just looking for new ways

Comment: Why is `runRefresh` static?

Comment: @ConnorsFan It was just static because I was experimenting.  I like your solution though. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call child component method from parent class - Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38974896/call-child-component-method-from-parent-class-angular)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `runRefresh` is a public method of the child component:

```
export class ChildComponent{
  public runRefresh() {
    ...
  }
}
```

you can call it directly in the parent template by referring to the child component with the help of a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables-var):

```
<button (click)="child.runRefresh()" />
<app-child-component #child></app-child-component>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bwaq6s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to write a service that provide an event, emit in parent, subscribe in the childs.

Another way:

You can write a directive that provides a component reference:

```
import { Directive, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[selectordirective]',
})
export class SelectorDirective  {
  constructor(public cmpRef: ChildComponent) { }
}
```

Attach it to your childs:

```
<app-child-component selectordirective> </app-child-component>
```

Use ViewChild to read the reference in `ParentComponent`:

```
@ViewChild(SelectorDirective) child !: SelectorDirective;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    child.cmpRef.runRefresh()
  }
```

Comment: Why not just a ViewChild of ChildComponent?