# Calling a function inside component which is used inside a ngTemplate

Tags: angular, typescript

parent-component.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent-component',
  templateUrl: './parent-component.component.html',
})
export class ParentComponentComponent {
  someFunction() {
    childComponent.someChildFunction()
  }
}
```

parent-component.component.html

```
<ngTemplate>
  <app-child-component></app-child-component>
</ngTemplate>
```

child-component.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child-component',
  templateUrl: './child-component.component.html',
})
export class ChildComponentComponent {
  someChildFunction() {
    //some usefull work
  }
}
```

child-component.component.html

```
<input [(ngmodel)]="search">
```

How to call the child function from the parent that is within the ngTemplate

i tried to it using the component reference.

```
@ViewChild(ChildComponentComponent)
  private childComponent: ChildComponentComponent;
```

but was undefined..
then tried

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template"></ng-container>
```

in parent component

That time any update inside the child component is not reflecting
like an input with ngModel.

Any help would be helpful. Or some better solution would also work..

Comment: [refer this it will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38974896/call-child-component-method-from-parent-class-angular)
You need to use @viewChild From that you can get child from parent

Comment: Why is the child component wrapped inside `<ngTemplate>`?

Comment: Actually I am using a ngx modal.. hence the component is wrapped in the ngTemplate..
Is it not the correct way?

Comment: Actually i can explain the full thing.. may be you will get a better idea..
I am using ngx bootstrap modal and the modal content are refered inside the ngTemplate. Now the content inside modal was reused in many place so i created a component out of it. basically its a form that gets in details. now the form submit button is in modal level and the save part is inside the reused  component. when i hit the submit button i want to hit the save part of the reused  component. 

Any better solution should be helpful