# Angular call child component method from parent component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a parent component having three instances of child component inside it.

**child-product-detail.component.html**

```
<form id="frmProduct" #frmProduct="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSave(frmProduct)">
   <ng-content select="[buttons-view]"></ng-content>
   <input type="text" id="txtProductName" name="txtProductName" [(ngModel)]="product.productName" />
</form>
```

**child-product-detail.component.ts**

```
onSave(form) {
    let isValid = this.validate(form);
    if (!isValid) return;
}
```

**parent-product.compoment.html**

```
<child-product-detail [product]="products[0]">
   <div buttons-view>
       <button type="button" class="btn" (click)="saveProduct(0)" >Save</button>                                    
   </div>
</child-product-detail>
<child-product-detail [product]="products[1]">
   <div buttons-view>
       <button type="button" class="btn" (click)="saveProduct(1)" >Save</button>                                    
   </div>
</child-product-detail>
<child-product-detail [product]="products[2]">
   <div buttons-view>
       <button type="button" class="btn" (click)="saveProduct(2)" >Save</button>                                    
   </div>
</child-product-detail>
```

**parent-product.component.ts**

```
saveProduct(productId) {
    let productToSave = this.products(productIndex);
    // Code required to call onSave method of child component
}
```

Is there anyway I can call onSave method of the child component passing the form object of it?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it could be possible to do that by using @ContentChildren, but you would be *much* better off if you posted the full description of what you're trying to accomplish and solved that actual problem in a different way. You're trying to do something that's usually an anti-pattern, for reasons that are very unclear.

Comment: why do you need to inject `button-views` content, and not add it directly in your `child-product-detail.component.ts`. Then use `*ngFor` to avoid to repeat 3 times same block.

Comment: @ThierryFalvo - I would like to reuse the child-product-detail at multiple places so I am trying to extract the functionality out of the child-product-details page.

Comment: @JoannaFalkowska - As mentioned in the above comment, I am trying to reuse the child-product-detail so  I am trying to extract the save functionality in the parent page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call child component method from parent class - Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38974896/call-child-component-method-from-parent-class-angular)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ViewChildren` decorator.

```
@ViewChildren(ChildProductDetailComponent)
childComponents: QueryList<ChildProductDetailComponent>;

saveProduct(productId) {
   this.childComponents.get(productIndex).onSave();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an eventemitter.

Assuming you have the child component with an output event function like this:

```
<app-product-stock (outputStockEvent)="outputStockEvent($event)"></app-product-stock>
```

Then this would be the function in the parent:

```
public outputStockEvent(event){
    this.stock = event
  }
```

and in the child component:

```
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.stockForm = this.fb.group({
          a: '',
          b: '',
          c:'',
        });
       }

.....
 

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.stockForm.valueChanges.subscribe(data =>{
          this.outputStockEvent.emit(data)
        })
      }
```

If you then use a "Save" button in the ParentComponent,
you can write the values into a final array:

```
public save(){
  let finalObj ={ "stock":this.stock"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it using the `@Output` directive to emit custom **events**.

For example:

**child-product-detail.component.ts**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

export class ChildProductDetailComponent {
    @Output() yourEventEmitter = new EventEmitter<any>();

    onSave(form) {
        let isValid = this.validate(form);
        if (isValid) {
            this.yourEventEmitter.emit(form)
        };
    }
```

When onSave() is executed, it emit the **yourEventEmitter**

**parent-product.compoment.html**

```
<child-product-detail (yourEventEmitter)="saveProduct($event)">
    <button type="button" class="btn" (click)="onSave(0)" >Save</button>
</child-product-detail>
```

Than the parent component got the event and run the function **saveProduct()** and receiving the form by the **$event.**

**parent-product.component.ts**

```
saveProduct(productId) {
    // the productId is the form from the child component
}
```

You cand learn more about it https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

Comment: Thanks @VitoNeto, however in this case I will have to add the save button in the child-product-details page so it will invoke the onSave method.

Comment: Yes, you still can do it how i'm saying, you just put the button inside the child component and call function that emit the event. Got it?

I edited the parent-product.compoment.html to you see.

Comment: I understood but I would like to keep the save button inside the parent component.

Comment: Create a service.ts.

import the service in child and parent component.ts.


In the service you create - yourEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();

In the parent your function will Emit the event - this.service.yourEvent.emit();

In the child you wait to the subscribe of yourEvent - ngOnInit() { this.service.yourEvent.subscribe(() => { // here you take the form pass to service and take from the service to the parent }) }

Comment: I did it locally. So, your button will be in the parent, when clicked will run a function inside the child.

Comment: thanks, it should allow to call the child component's method this way. However, how can I pass the form object to onSave(form) method?